# Facebook Graph API not returning all results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In the Facebook Graph API Explorer (and also via PHP SDK), `/act_9876543/adsets?fields=campaign_id,ads{name}&filtering=[{field: "id",operator:"IN", value: ['334455']}]` correctly returns adset 334455 (and its ads) and shows that its campaign_id is 122222.

However, the result of `/act_9876543/campaigns?fields=adsets{name,ads{name}}&filtering=[{field: "id",operator:"IN", value: ['122222']}]` **does NOT include adset 334455 (even though it should, according to [the "Nested Requests" docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion), right?)**.

Similiarly, the result of `/campaigns?fields=adsets.limit(5000){ads.limit(5000){name},name},name&limit=5000` **is missing many adsets and ads**. (I'd expect it to return *everything* because I have fewer than 50 total campaigns, and each campaign has fewer than 50 adsets, and each adset has fewer than 50 ads).

Am I misunderstanding how Nested Requests should work?

Comment: What do you get when you leave out the filtering part in the second request, does adset 334455 show up in the result then?

Comment: @misorude No, when I run `/act_9876543/campaigns?fields=adsets{name,ads{name}}&limit=5000`, I do not see 334455. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Field expansion should give you the same results as “normal” requests, in theory at least. File a bug report maybe, and ask Facebook to look into this? https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs